# Error using paperclip to upload two different files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am using paperclip to upload an image and an audio file but I noticed that after uploading the two files, the audio file is damaged making it unusable. I tried uploading only the audio file and it works fine but if I upload the both of then at the same time the audio file uploads but does not work again. Can anybody please tell me why this might be happening? and how to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works just fine on rails 3.0.9 with parperclip 2.5.0,

inside your model:

```
has_attached_file :image

has_attached_file :mp3

validates_attachment_content_type :mp3, :content_type => [ 'application/mp3','application/x-mp3', 'audio/mpeg', 'audio/mp3' ],
            :message => 'Please select a .mp3 file'
```

Comment: thanks for this do i have solved the issue a long time ago so i forgot about the question. thanks